# CardView is wrap_content list item instead of match_parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Card View  wrapping content instead of match parent. All list items is wrapped instead of matching its width. 
[image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout      
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/Album_Art"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_google_music" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/song_name"
                android:id="@+id/Sname"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Album_Art"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Album_Art" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/artist_album"
                android:id="@+id/Sdata"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Album_Art"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Album_Art"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manually setting width works. When i set it to a large dp value, it works fine, except that the list item is out of the window. I don't understand why match_parent doesn't work. Any leads on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that you're passing null for the parent when you inflate the layout in your `Adapter`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, what do I have to pass?

Comment: The `ViewGroup` passed into the method where you're inflating the layout. Probably named `parent`.

Comment: Try to set `TextView` to match_parent in xml

Comment: @MikeM. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a recyclerView ?
if so, you should override this on layoutmanager like this :

```
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
                return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `RecyclerViewAdapter`, make sure you are using the first signature of inflate method instead of the second in the `onCreateViewHolder`.

```
1. inflate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)  

2. inflate(LayoutInflater inflater)
```

And, be sure to pass *parent* for root & *true/false* for attachToRoot.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this was the problem with me.